# You must include AdActivity in your Manifest.xml

Tags: android

I am getting an error that you must declare AdActivity in manifest file.
I did that even, I followed all steps but still getting errors.
Someone Help Please, Here is my code and xml and Manifest file.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="fill" >

 <com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/googleAd"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="i_don't_want_to_share_my_id"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" >
</com.google.ads.AdView>
```

Manifest File.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.admob"
android:installLocation="auto"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" >
</uses-permission>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />

    <activity
        android:name=".Main"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

I have also included the latest admob jar file.
Can someOne help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in configChanges

```
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

Also adjust the target property in your project's project.properties. This should be at least 13.

```
target=android-13
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 2):

```
<activity
        android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />


change the above code to


<activity
        android:name="com.example.admob.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
```

Comment: whether adview is the program created by you